# Inserting multiple data values to a field in mysql table

Tags: mysql

I have a table with column

```
merchant_id | phone
 1          | 879182782
 2          | 324239324
```

now what i want is a query to insert multiple values for phone field

```
merchant_id | phone
  1         | 879182782,989838273
  2         | 324239324,849238420,349289393
```

Can anyone help me with example query? I tried update and all but couldn't work

Comment: No you should not want that.  Multiple values in a single string column is very, very poor database design.  What you should want is a separate table, called a junction table, with one column for merchant and one for phone, and multiple rows for a merchant with multiple phones.

Comment: ya, I agree with you sir, I have been reading all the questions on this topic and found that its not a good way of doing it, but its a requirement that is given to me by my professor and whatever I need to give the result. Plz any solutions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with Gordon, but with you want anyway, you can use "CONCAT", here an example for you:

```
create table tabla(
    merchant_id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    phone text
);

insert into tabla(merchant_id,phone)
VALUES (1,'809-541-8935');

insert into tabla(merchant_id,phone)
VALUES (2,'809-541-8935');

insert into tabla(merchant_id,phone)
VALUES (3,'809-541-8935');

UPDATE tabla 
SET phone = concat(phone, ',809-537-7791')
where merchant_id = 1
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ed25e)

Comment: Thats good!!! Thanks.. Now if my merchant_id is a foreign key in this table this doesnt work perfectly.                                                                              This query works for that                                                                          >>> insert into merchant_phone(merchant_id,phone) values((select id from merchant where id="0000test"),'7672665642');

Comment: you are welcome :) , do you have merchant_id like a foreign key? @vinay

Comment: Yes, The merchant_id is a foreign key, which is a primary key in merchant table .. i should be able to add multiple contact to the above table and when i execute select query to view contact numbers then it should show all the contacts including the one in merchant table..

Comment: can you attach the structure of you db? @vinay